# Objective C - Navigate automatically from textfield to textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I need to have 3 textfields and each textfield should input only 1 number (maximum length of textfield is 1).
My question is how to automatically navigate from textfield1, textfield2, textfield3 after the user enter a number?

Comment: google `becomeFirstResponder`

Answer (score 2):

Set the tag of your textfield1, textfield2, textfield3 to 0,1 and 2 respectively and try following code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ((textField.text.length == 0 && string.length == 1 && [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] isSupersetOfSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string]]) || string.length == 0) {
       // Try to find next responder
        if (!(string.length == 0))
            [self performSelector:@selector(changeResponder:) withObject:textField afterDelay:0.2];
        return YES;
    } else {
        if (textField.text.length == 1) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(changeResponder:) withObject:textField afterDelay:0.2];
        }
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)changeResponder:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    UIResponder *nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` delegate method. Based on the text being entered into the text field you can call `becomeFirstResponder` on the next text field.

Keep in mind that what you want to do has lots of complications. What happens if the user pastes in a bunch of text into a text field? What happens if the user goes back to a text field that already has a value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {    
  if (theTextField == textField1 && YOUR_CONDITION_TO_COMPLETION_OF_EDITING){    
     [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];    
  }
}
```

Add similiar conditions for other text fields also